# Jquery trim this and set value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting a Invalid left-hand side in assignment error when running this jQuery command. Whats wrong with it and why isn't it working?

I'm trying to get a value from a field trim it then reset it.

```
$(this).val() = $.trim($(this).val());
```

Comment: You can't assign value to a function call.

Comment: @jcubic: True, but you can pass a function to `val()` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery method `val()` is a setter and a getter. If you want to set the value, do:

`$(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));`

Next time please read [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/) first.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with callback function of **[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)**

```
$(this).val(function(i,v){ return $.trim(v); });
```

or using javascript

```
this.value = this.value.trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply it to multiple items, with a single line of code, use `val` with a function:

```
$(':input').val(function(){ return $.trim($(this).val()) });
```

or

```
$(':input').val(function(i, val){ return $.trim(val) });
```

Note: this obviously also works for a single item.

e.g.

```
$(this).val(function(i, val){ return $.trim(val) });
```